# how to insert <div id="result"></div> value within input in php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am calculating response from two inputs with ajax and then i want to save the result in the database.
The result i am getting is by this way

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Now i want to call the result in input tag so i can save it into my database

like

```
<input type="text" name="result" id="result" value="<div id="result"></div>">
```

But this is not working

Tried this just now, and not working as well. No value is getting stored in database

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-floating mb-3">
      <div id="result"></div>
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="resultcal" id="textBoxId" value="">
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var tmstatusText = $('#result').text();
        $('#textBoxId').val(tmstatusText);
         });
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

Calculation AJAX Code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      // Trigger AJAX request when input values change
      $("#inv_amount, #units").on("input", function () {
          var inv_amount = $("#inv_amount").val();
          var units = $("#units").val();
          // Perform AJAX request
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "calculate.php",
              data: {
                inv_amount: inv_amount,
                units: units
              },
              success: function (response) {
                  $("#result").html(response);
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Form Code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-floating mb-3">
       <div id="result"></div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="result" id="result" value="<div id="result"></div>">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't put " characters inside an HTML attribute value that's quoted with "

Comment: You can't put a `<div>` inside a `value`, nor should you need to. You can just query the `<input>` for its value. But your code makes no reference to the `result` input, and `input` is not an event. Try adding your event handler to `submit`.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular "input" is most certainly an event, and while I would agree it's weird, putting HTML in an input value is perfectly fine.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same ID, that isn't valid and can cause bugs

Comment: Anyway you can just put the output from the ajax call directly into the result textbox, without needing the div

Comment: Can you please let me know how. I am stuck in this from 2 hours, tried everything that i know

Comment: Just remove `<div id="result"></div>` entirely from your page. Then replace `$("#result").html(response)` with `$("#result").val(response)`

Comment: After that of course there is still a need for that form where the "result" input is to be submitted to the server,  and some code to save it to the database. We don't know if you've written that code or if it is correct or not

Comment: thank you. what should i write in value="" then? 
i mean like this
<input type="text" name="result" value="<?php echo $result ?>">

Comment: You don't need to write anything in that attribute. `$("#result").val(response)` sets the value, when it gets the data back from the ajax request. Before that moment there is nothing to write.

Comment: all of my data is saving in the database by $_POST['name']; etc

Comment: apology from me by being dumb now, scratching head and now tired. I tried this

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="units" id="" value="">

and replaced with $("#result").val(response)

But still nothing

Comment: Do you mean you don't see anything in the input box? Try to be precise about the problem, please. If so, well, have you verified that the ajax call is executed and that `response` contains some data? Use the JS debugger and/or add in some console.log() calls to track what the code is doing

Comment: yes input field shows nothing. But ajax call is giving results. I mean when called <div id="result"></div> shows the data properly.

Comment: am i missing some id="" in <input tag>

Comment: That's strange and doesn't seem to make sense. Can you edit the question to show your latest code, and also provide a sample value you are seeing in the `response` variable. Thanks

Comment: Adyson, thanks a lot. Your idea worked and i was missing id="result" in the end. You saved my day

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="units" id="result" value="">

this is correct now. i was missing id="result"

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `<div id="result"></div>` entirely from your page.

Then replace `$("#result").html(response)` with `$("#result").val(response)`

That way you write the data directly into the input textbox, and also it removes the element with a duplicate ID.